# CKQueryOperation returning no results when sort descriptors are used

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckqueryoperation

I am working on a CloudKit based project where it would be very helpful to use sort descriptors to get the most recent results from the database.

```
func getConversationPosts(for targetConversation: MessageConversation, completionHandler: @escaping ([MessagePost]) -> Void) {
       var post = MessagePost()
       let getRecordsOperation = CKQueryOperation()
        getRecordsOperation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
        getRecordsOperation.resultsLimit = 1
        getRecordsOperation.query = CKQuery(recordType: "MessagePost", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "conversationName = %@", targetConversation.conversationID.recordName))
        getRecordsOperation.query?.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)] // If you comment this out results are returned
        /*getPostsOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {(searchCursor, error) in
            print("sQ: \(searchCursor)")
        }*/
        getRecordsOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {(postRecord) in
            let newPost = MessagePost()
            newPost.textContent = postRecord.value(forKey: "textContent") as! String
            newPost.poster = User(userName: postRecord.value(forKey: "postUser") as! String)
           // posts.append(newPost)
            post = newPost
        }
        getRecordsOperation.completionBlock = {() in
            completionHandler(post)
        }
        OperationQueue().addOperation(getRecordsOperation)
}
```

The above code always works if the line that adds the `sortDescriptors` is removed. Even without a result limit, if any sort descriptor is added, the `recordFetchedBlock` isn't even called, but the completion block is. What could be causing this?

Comment: Does it work if you sort on one of your own record fields instead of "creationDate"?

Comment: @rmaddy This code does work when using a custom field.

Comment: Have you set this field to sortable.

Comment: @agibson007 to clarify, are you asking if I set the custom field to be sortable? This particular record was actually created programmatically, not in the CloudKit dashboard. I think that makes its fields sortable by default.

Comment: I am not sure if creation date is sortable by default. Go into the dashboard and look.

Comment: What’s the word on this?  Did you actually check the dashboard to make sure.

Comment: @agibson007 I checked the Dashboard and I made createdAt sortable. That seems to have solved the issue.